# Editing Registry With VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, registry

I'm just familiarising myself to edit registry in VB. I am having a problem with changing a value in the **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`** key. When ever I change a value at runtime it always assumes that I am going in the "Wow6432Node" key, even though I don't put that in the parenthesis. Example: **`My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\SHOWALL", "CheckedValue", 1)`**
  and it doesn't change the value in the string above, but changes it as if I have put **`"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\SHOWALL"`** in the string.

The program is running as administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called [registry redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  In 64 bit Windows some registry keys (including HKLM\Software) are redirected for 32 bit applications.  If you changed the build properties on your VB.NET project to x64 you would see it write to HKLM\Software.  You can [access the non-redirected keys using flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I believe those are only available for the unmanaged APIs.

But the short answer is you not doing anything wrong, and that how it is supposed to work.

Comment: The RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey() method in .NET 4 provides a workaround with the RegistryView argument.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the replies =] Ohh and one more thing. 64-bit operating systems have the x86 right? Does that mean that the x86 is the 64-bit operating system or the x64 is the 64-bit operating system. If you get what I mean =].

Comment: 64-bit Windows can run 32 bit code.  In this context x86 refers to to 32-bit code and x64 to 64 bit code.